# Not able to select any options in dojo Select

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I am using dojo 1.6 and the problem I have encountered is quite unique. Check out the following code:

```
var dd = new dijit.form.Select({
        id: 'dd', 
        options: [{label:'option1'}, {label: 'option2'}],
    }); 
dojo.connect(dd, "onChange", this, function (){
        console.debug("trying to catch the change");
    });
```

So as per the above code I should be getting a drop down and be able to change the value in the drop and catch the event in `dojo.connect`. While I do get a drop down which by default has `option1` selected, however I am not able to select `option2`. Please note that both the options are visible in the drop down but the selection doesn't work. 
I am fairly new at dojo but from all the examples this seems to be the minimum requirement to make a drop down. I would appreciate any feedback. 
EDIT: 
So turns out if I set options like `[{label: 'option1', value: 1}, {label: 'option2', value:2}]` then everything works as I want to. But can some one please explain what is the role of value here and why does it have to be in integer all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is the text that will be sent to the server if you submit a form containing your select.

It's similar to an `option` tag with a value attribute: `<option value="op1">option1</option>`. If you omit the value attribute on tag, the submitted text will simply be the label text "option1".

The values don't have to be integers - you can have options with `{label: foo, value: foo}`, as long as foo is unique among the options. If you omit the value property here, the submitted value will be undefined, and the dijit will (as you've noticed) behave generally strange.

**Edit after a bit of experimentation:** When using the Select dijit, the values in the `options` array (or, in fact, the ids in a store) must be strings. Otherwise, giving the select a default value will not work. E.g.:

```
new Select({
    value: 3,
    options: [ {label: "foo", value: 1}, {label: "bar", value: 3}]
})
```

.. will *not* set "bar" as the default selected option, and highlighting the selected item in the dropdown doesn't work. You have to use an option array with string values:

```
    options: [ {label: "foo", value: "1"}, {label: "bar", value: "3"}]
```

Not 100% sure about the reason behind this.

Comment: I am yet to try to a string as my value but I know if I used a number like 123499 then it still ends up behaving strangely. For some reason, or at least, in my case it had to be 1, 2, 3, .. so on. Thanks for the explanation though!

Comment: I faintly recall having some issues with ids being numbers in stores, but not directly in the select dijit. In the case of stores, I had to cast the id numbers to strings. I think it has something to do with the object property order not being guaranteed for numerical property names, but someone else could answer that better.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that or what version of dojo you are using? Because right now I am using dojo 1.6 and I don't need to assign string values. I guess you will have to keep them strings if you jump out of sequence. ex: `options:[{label:"foo", value: 1}, {label:"bar", value: 2}]` works fine for me. However, if I skip `2` then I do need to make them strings as you have shown. Also, one more way to change the default value is `options:[{label:"foo", value: 1}, {label:"bar", value: 2, selected: true}]`. Not sure if this will work in your version.

Comment: @Shay Seems to behave similarly in >= 1.6, didn't try earlier versions. See here http://fiddle.jshell.net/froden/LjHFk/2/